# Group cols in row in SQL PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql

Need group 3 col in 1 row

I have this table:

This query:

```
select cidade, grupo from dados;
```

```
|----------|--------|  
|Cidade    |Grupo   |  
|----------|--------|  
|varginha  |grande  |  
|----------|--------|  
|mimoso    |pequena |  
|----------|--------|  
|Sao Tumas |media   |  
|----------|--------|
```

But, I need convert, or grouping cols in row in SQL, like this:

```
|---------|  
|Grouping |    
|---------|  
|varginha |  
|grande   |  
|---------|  
|mimoso   |     
|pequena  |  
|---------|  
|Sao Tumas|  
|media    |  
|---------|
```

Comment: In your resultset, does each block (like `varginha grande`) represents a single record, or two different records?

Comment: each line is single record. like: line 1 - varginha, grande / line 2 - mimoso pequena / line 3 - sao tumas, media

Comment: OK. So what is wrong with the answer by Gordon Linoff? It seems to return the proper results for your sample data.

Answer (score 1):

What you are trying to do is called *concatenation* in SQL realm. `GROUP BY` is completely a different beast ([more info](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_groupby.asp)).

In your case, you want to put a *new line* in between: first column + new line + second column. In Postgres, using `chr(10)` you'll get the *new line* character, so:

```sql
postgres=# SELECT CONCAT("cidade", CHR(10), "grupo") AS "Grouping" FROM "dados";

 Grouping
----------
varginha
grande

mimoso
pequena

Sao Tumas
media
(3 rows)
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you just looking for `concat()`:

```
select (cidade || ' ' || grupo) as grouping
from t;
```

You can put a new line as the separator.  Usually, I don't recommend this unless you have a good reason.

Comment: I need the convert results of 2 cols in 2 rows. concat not work for me.

Comment: @AlisonRibeiro . . . Your data has 2 columns and 3 rows.  The result set looks like it has 3 rows, so your comment does not make sense.

Answer (score 0):

Well...
I Resolve this question using UNION ALL

Like this:

select cidade as col_data from dados
union all
select grupo as col_data from dados;